# Persisting data from Redis to MongoDB for datastore

Tags: caching, mongodb, redis

I have an application that makes use of frequently updated lists.  So for example, every person that clicks a button, gets added to a unique list associated to that button.  Then we'll want to display these lists, by button, in descending order and with a limit.

We've been doing this using MySQL and Memcache.  The problem is this does not work well.

What I plan to do is use Redis lists.  Each button will hold a unique key in redis, each user will be added to the key using `LPUSH` If we want to get the latest 10, we can use `LRANGE 0 10`

Now, eventually these buttons will 'expire' and no longer be actively added to or clicked, however, we'll want historic data.  The idea is once these expire, we will get the data from Redis and populate it to MongoDB.  Any queries on the historic data, will be against the MongoDB.

Would anyone suggest against this solution? Does it "make sense" to do it this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution makes sense, I do something similar in my app.

One thing to note, though:

> So for example, every person that clicks a button, gets added to a unique list associated to that button.

Do you allow duplicate users in that list? If yes, use lists. If not, you might want to couple it with set (for unique checks), but it'll cost you some RAM.

Comment: The critical point you may want to explain further to the OP is how to transfer items from Redis to MongoDB when they expire. It is not possible to be directly notified when an item expires in Redis.

Comment: @DidierSpezia: Note how "expire" is quoted in the question. This hints (to me) that it is application who decides when item is expired. It can as well transfer data to mongo at this point.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes, expiration will be handled by the app, once a button expires, the app will know this and copy the data from redis to mongo, then remove from redis.   The lists can also have duplicate users, so lists should be good.