# How to improve the performance of feed system using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, redis, feed

I have a feed system using fan-out on write. I keep a list of feed ids in redis sorted set, and save the feed content in mongodb, so every time when i read 30 feeds, i have to do 30 query to mongodb, is there anyway to improve it ?

Comment: why do you need to read 30 feeds if you do fanout ?

Answer (score 1):

Its depend upon your setup of database. MongoDb has a vast documentation about how to increase simultaneous read and write [MongoDb conncurrency](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/)

1. If you need so many writes in database with less latency starts using sharding [Deployment Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/).
2. If you need to increase number of reads in data base deploy each shards as replica set and rout your read query in secondary node [Read Prefences](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/)
3. Also each query should covered by index [Better indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/), you can check your query time by simply adding explain after a find it will show you the time and all facts

   ```
   db.collection.find({a:"abcd"}).explain()
   ```
4. Make sure you have enough ram so that your data set fits with ram atleast your index should fit inside the ram coz each time a data fetched from disk is 10 times slower than RAM.
5. Check your sever status with running [MongoStat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#bin.mongostat) it will measures your database performance , page fault , lock , query opertaion manny detail.
6. Also measure your hardware performance with program like iostat and make sure io wait is low and less than 1%.
7. Few good links to deployment of mongodb and performance tuning.

   1. [Production deployment of mongodb](https://blog.serverdensity.com/notes-from-a-production-mongodb-deployment/)

   2. [Performance tuning of mongodb By 10gen](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2012/mongodb-performance-tuning)

   3. [Using redis before mongodb to cache query and result object](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/redis-and-mongodb-can-work)

   4. [Example of redis and mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959654/persisting-data-from-redis-to-mongodb-for-datastore?rq=1)